# importing js file in Vue project throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobius1-selectr

I did a `npm install mobius1-selectr`

and imported it in my `main.js`

```
import 'mobius1-selectr/dist/selectr.min.css';
import 'mobius1-selectr/dist/selectr.min.js';
```

but as soon I import I get this exception:

```
You must supply either a HTMLSelectElement or a CSS3 selector string.
```

which comes from the source of selectr.

Is the import not to be done this way in webpack / main.js?

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried solutions proposed at: https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr/issues/31 or https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-properly-initialize-npm-installed-js-library-in-laravel-54 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your imports are incorrect. This library uses UMD to export `Selectr` constructor. You are using Webpack so default import in your case should work:

```
import Selectr from 'mobius1-selectr'
```

Comment: thank you but that doesn't help. I tried `import {Selectr} from 'mobius1-selectr/dist/selectr.min.js';` as well as `import Selectr from 'mobius1-selectr/dist/selectr.min.js'; and `import Selectr from 'mobius1-selectr'` still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: `import Selectr from 'mobius1-selectr'` is how you should do it. Show how you are using `Selectr`.

Comment: `import Selectr from 'mobius1-selectr'` doesn't work. Still getting the same error. Further I have not used Selectr at all. I am just trying to integrate the library but as soon as I import I get this error.

Comment: Well here is a proof that it should work: https://codesandbox.io/s/l99y6m401z. If it doesn't for you then there is something else. Also this error indicates the you *are* using Selectr, as this error is thrown when you invoke this function (with incorrect parameters).

Comment: I am stunned! I am fairly certain I have not called this function anywhere. I will check why this is happening. Thank you. One last question how did you know that it has to be import Selectr and not import 'path to js' meaning how did you know it is UMD?

Comment: I checked source code and saw that this package uses UMD patten (see package.json main field). Also you almost never want to use path to import stuff (maybe only CSS). Then since you are using Webpack you can import this library with either `require` or `import`.